# Passing a range of a pandas data raises KeyError

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas

I was having no problem at all doing this:

```
fun_abc(datax.time,datax.data,20)
```

of which datax is a `pandas.DataFrame` in which `time` and `data` are the columns.

However, when I try to pass a range into the function, I get a `KeyError: 0`.

```
fun_abc(datax.time[100:120],datax.data[100:120],20)
```

I could not get my head around it. Could you please kindly help?
Thank you for your attention!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you do `datax.time[100:120]` you no longer can access index 0.

For example:

```
In [36]: import pandas as pd

In [37]: import numpy as np

In [38]: df = pd.DataFrame(np.arange(12).reshape(4,3))

In [39]: df[0][1:3]
Out[39]: 
1    3
2    6
Name: 0, dtype: int64

In [40]: df[0][1:3][0]
```

Results in `KeyError: 0`

Comment: Thanks @Akavall! I figured it out myself too. I will accept your answer! Sorry for the troubles!

Answer (score 1):

Hie, I figured out what is wrong.

Whenever a `pandas.Series` object is passed into a function, it brings with itself the corresponding ORIGINAL index. And this is where it goes wrong.

I write an additional checking routine to resolve the error:

```
if isinstance(var_a, pd.Series):
        var_a_ini = var_a.index[0]
    else:
        var_a_ini = var_a[0]
```

Extra care should be taken in the case of dealing with `pandas.Series` when you sliced part of it out to pass into a function which operates based on the reference of an index.